# $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2^k}):F]=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Prove that there are exactly $3$ fields $F$ with $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2^k}):F]=2$   for any $k \geq 3$.

I have done the particular case for $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$. But how to do this general case?

Comment: What is the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2^k})/\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{2^k}^*$

Comment: Now by basic Galois theory you have to find the subgroups of order $2$, which is the same as finding the elements of order $2$.

Comment: do you have an hint for proving the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^k})/ \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by hand for $\;k=1,2\;$ as you've already done for $\;k=3\;$ . In general, we have

$$\text{for}\;\;k\ge3\;,\;\;\Bbb Z_{2^k}\cong C_2\times C_{2^{k-2}}$$

If we write $\;C_2=\langle a\rangle \;,\;\;C_{2^{k-2}}=\langle b\rangle\;$ , then $\;(a,1)\,,\,\,(1,b)\,,\,(a,b)\;$ are all the elements of order two in the group. Now just take the fixed fields and etc.

Comment: ? what is $C_{2^{k-2}}$ ? (it is not cyclic it is the mutlplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{k-1}}$)

Comment: $\;C_m=\;$ the cyclic (multiplicative) group of order $\;m\;$

Comment: ok, but the multiplicative group of units modulo $2^k$ is not cyclic.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I know...who said or implied otherwise? From I answer that is obvious.

Comment: this group is a finite abelian group and hence it can be written as direct product of cyclic groups.